# How to solve "gpg: symmetric encryption of `[stdin]' failed: Broken pipe"?

Tags: linux, encryption, sftp, gnupg

I'm getting the following error when I've tried to rub backup to the SFTP server:

```
gpg: iobuf_flush failed on close: Broken pipe
gpg: symmetric encryption of `[stdin]' failed: Broken pipe
```

[image: gpg: iobuf_flush failed on close: Broken pipe gpg: symmetric encryption of `[stdin]' failed: Broken pipe]

The Google search for this error didn't yield any useful information, so I would appreciate any suggestions.

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: Please [edit] your question and copy&paste the command that resulted in the error message.